# React native: having issues with npm start after removing the node_modules

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am having issues running my expo app after deleting the node modules. I ran npm start but after trying to open it on an IOS simulator or the web, I got this:

```
Unable to resolve module ./LocalAssets from /Users/mouhamadou/Documents/Dksen/dksen-app/node_modules/expo-asset/build/Asset.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/expo-asset/build/LocalAssets(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * node_modules/expo-asset/build/LocalAssets/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
> 1 | import { Platform } from '@unimodules/core';
  2 | import { getAssetByID } from './AssetRegistry';
  3 | import * as AssetSources from './AssetSources';
  4 | import * as AssetUris from './AssetUris';
```

Comment: _Why_ did you remove `node_modules`?

Comment: I was installing a google maps extension that wasn't working

Comment: have you tried to use ```npm install``` again before running the app?

Comment: Yes, solved it with expo start -c

Answer (score 0):

Alright, solved it using `expo start -c` command